# Set up one or more character before string with regex expression in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

Requirements for query:

[one or more character]%[first name]_[last name]%[zero or more characters]

Current solution:

```
SELECT first_name, second_name, attribute
FROM users
WHERE attribute
REGEXP BINARY concat('%', first_name, '_', second_name, '%');
```

Output:

```
first_name    second_name    attribute
Mikel    Cover    %Mikel_Cover%
Vicenta    Kravitz    0%Vicenta_Kravitz%
Shayne    Dahlquist    0R0V331K8Q7ypBi4Az3B6Nm0jCqUk%Shayne_Dahlquist%46E3O0u7t7
Mikel    Kravitz    PBX86iw1Ied87Z9OarE6sdSLdt%Mikel_Kravitz%W73XOY9YaOgi060r2x12D2EmD7
```

First row shouldn`t be printed because of first requirement.

My suggestions:

```
+, +[[:digit:]]+|[[:alpha:]]+$, '%%'

REGEXP BINARY concat('+%', first_name, '_', second_name, '%');
```

How to change the query to avoid first row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may fix the regex in the following way:

```
WHERE attribute REGEXP BINARY concat('.+%', first_name, '_', second_name, '%');
```

By adding `.+` you require  any 1 or more chars before the first `%` in your pattern. Actually, it will suffice to use just `.` since `REGEXP` allows partial matches.

If you want to assure the char before `%` is an alphanumeric char, use `[[:alnum:]]` instead of the dot:

```
WHERE attribute REGEXP BINARY concat('[[:alnum:]]%', first_name, '_', second_name, '%');
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
```